# Mysql stored procedure slow for delete statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an odd mysql query speed problem i am trying to wrap my head around. I was moving a mysql database from one server to another and a server that should have been much more robust was almost 4 times as slow running certain mysql queries than the original server. After a few days of debugging, i finally figure out that there was a huge difference in speed depending on how variable were being used in a where clause in a stored procedure. Here are some examples:

fast:

```
set @s = Concat('delete from visitids where VisitID=''',xVisitID,''' and OrgCode=''',xOrgCode,'''');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

slow:

```
delete from visitids where VisitID=xVisitID and OrgCode=xOrgCode;
```

slow:

```
set @s = Concat('delete from visitids where VisitID=xVisitID and OrgCode=xOrgCode');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
```

The first example is about 5 times faster than the next 2 examples. The other odd thing is it depends on the server and possibly mysql version. On one server, it doesn't matter how the variables are used in the where clause but on another server it does. Am i missing something? Why would a straight sql statement with a variable in a where clause be so significantly slower than one with an sql query built from a string and prepared/executed?

Comment: The third example simply won't work, as the `xVisitID` and `xOrgCode` variables won't exist within the scope of statement execution; perhaps you meant to show them parameterised instead?  In any event, do all the same indexes exist on all servers?

Comment: The last example should have been rewritten as set @s = Concat('delete from visitids where VisitID=@xVisitID and OrgCode=@xOrgCode'); 
with those variables being declared and set. The data and indexes are exactly the same. I saw this when i did a mysqldump of one server and imported it to another server.

Answer (score 0):

I met same problem. In sp, the delete is very slow. When run delete statement directly, the delete statement is very fast.